# Importance of Bernoulli Numbers

Tags: computer-science, bernoulli-numbers

I'm writing a research paper on the foundations of computing. Supposedly Ada Lovelace wrote an algorithm to find Bernoulli numbers. It sounds cool, but it won't mean anything to my history teacher.  What are some practical uses of Bernoulli numbers and why are they important? Thanks!

Comment: You can begin with the Wikipedia article. Googling will get many hits.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well, there was a reason that I came to the stack exchange website.... But cool, I'll look into that further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bernoulli numbers are related to Fermat's Last Theorem, which your history teacher may be familiar with. Ernst Kummer was able to prove Fermat's last theorem for all primes $p$ except for those which divide the numerator of a Bernoulli number. The reason is related to the class numbers of cyclotomic fields.

Comment: Okay, cool. Are there any "real world" applications?

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of "real world". They also appear in the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will do some more research. Hopefully, if it sounds professional, my teacher will just go with it :)